# How to run a for loop using a data frame and output a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to generate a data frame that uses a for loop(possibly) in the existing data frame to generate the info and either replace or write a new df

I have a very large data frame, and I want to generate a new data frame comparing all rows to a single reference row in the data frame. The new data frame would simply say T(true) if the cell matched the same column cell in the reference row, or F(false) if it did not.

given a data frame (df):

```
Name pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4
JU1  6    7    9    8
JU2  6    4    5    7
JU3  6    7    5    4
JU4  4    8    5    4
```

I want to use JU3 as my reference row to generate a new df with the same column and row titles that will return a true(T) for all the cells in each row that match the reference row and a false(F) if it does not.

The expected result would be a data frame(df2):

```
   Name pos1 pos2 pos3 pos4
   JU1  T    T    F    F 
   JU2  T    F    T    F
   JU3  T    T    T    T
   JU4  F    F    T    T
```

I have been playing with for loops with if-else commands but I am new to coding generally so I haven't been getting very far. Im not entirely sure if I can simply overwrite the existing data frame or it makes more sense to write a new csv file or table entirely. Im sure this is a very easy problem but any help or direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the reference value? Is it dynamic or always the same?

Comment: Here's a start: `z == z[rep(3, nrow(z)),]`

Comment: @NelsonGon apologize for the late response, it is always the same. I will try those suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
ref1<-c(6,7,5,4)
cbind(Name=df$Name,as.data.frame(purrr::map2(df[,-1],ref1,function(x,y) x==y)))


Name  pos1  pos2  pos3  pos4
1  JU1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2  JU2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3  JU3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4  JU4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

"Automate"

```
ref2<-as.vector(df[df$Name=="JU3",-1])
cbind(Name=df$Name,as.data.frame(purrr::map2(df[,-1],ref2,function(x,y) x==y)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we extract the row with a condition based on the 'Name', replicate the row to make the dimensions same with original data and do a comparison (`==`)

```
cbind(df[1], df[-1] == df[df$Name == "JU3", -1][rep(1, nrow(df)), ])
#   Name  pos1  pos2  pos3  pos4
#1  JU1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#2  JU2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#3  JU3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#4  JU4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("JU1", "JU2", "JU3", "JU4"), pos1 = c(6L, 
 6L, 6L, 4L), pos2 = c(7L, 4L, 7L, 8L), pos3 = c(9L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), pos4 = c(8L, 7L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```